# iPhone Application Themes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I tried using a multi-value settings bundle to change the view.  I would do the if statements in the applicationdidfinishloading in the application delegate.  Apparently the method isn't called every time the app is loaded, and it would not work correctly.

If anyone has done this, or has any suggestions, links to tutorials.  I would really appreciate it.  I'm just trying to load views (nibs) based on user preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can put your code in

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

or

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
```

methods also because from iOS 4.0 due to multitasking your app is just in the background state so it wont call applicationdidfinishloading method when the user presses the icon of your app again.

Comment: applicationDidBecomeActive actually solved the problem, thanks